# Capturing Button Methods from a second Form using PyQT

Tags: qt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I am super new to PyQT ... I am using QT Designer for my forms. I am confused about where to put my event handling for the second form in my project.

I have the following .py files :

- main.py
- Ui_make_render_folders.py (generated from the Qt designer ui file)
- Ui_prefs.py (generated from the Qt designer ui file)
- Mainwindow.py (this is where all the even handling for the main form
  lives)
- icons_rc.py (resource file)
- make_render_folders.py (where all my custom functions live)

Here is a picture of the script running :

[click to see script running](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4r22rb4shvptvc/render_folder_gen.JPG) << CLICK HERE

My question is ... where does the even handling for my prefs window go ???? I cant figure out where to put my [b]on_btn_released() for the buttons on y 2nd form.[/b] Also I am not sure I am instantiating that dialog properly. Currently I am adding this code to the top of my MainWindow.py.

Finally what does @pyqSignature("") do ? And do I need it ?

```
"""
This is where all teh MainWindow logic sits
"""
import os
import os.path
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow,  QFileDialog,  QTreeWidgetItem, QDialog
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignature,  QString
from make_folders import make_render_folders
from Ui_make_render_folders import Ui_MainWindow
from Ui_prefs import Ui_prefs



class Prefs(QDialog,  Ui_prefs):
def __init__(self, parent = None):
    QDialog.__init__(self,  parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

@pyqtSignature("")
def on_btn_get_ref_dir_released(self):
    print '2nd form'

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self, parent = None):
    """
    Constructor
    """
    QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.prefs = QDialog()
    ui = Ui_prefs()
    ui.setupUi(self.prefs)

@pyqtSignature("")
def on_btn_process_released(self):
    print 'process'
    no_of_shots = self.spn_no_of_shots.value()

    #spot_path = self.le_proj_path.text()+'\\'+self.lst_spots.selectedItems()[0].text()
    spot_path_string = 'self.le_proj_path.text())+os.sep,'
    spot_path_string += str(self.lst_spots.selectedItems()[0].text())    
    os.path.join(spot_path_string)                                                                      

    save_position = self.lst_spots.selectedItems()[0]

    if no_of_shots > 0:
        if self.cmb_mode.currentText() == 'Create Shots':
            print ('creating shots')
            for x in range(1, no_of_shots+1):
                make_render_folders.create_shot_folder(spot_path,  x)
        else:   
            print ('inserting shots')
            if self.lst_shots.count() > 0:
                t =self.lst_shots.selectedItems()[0].text()
                cur_shot = t[2:]
                cur_shot_val = int(cur_shot)
                cur_index = self.lst_shots.currentRow()
                print('sel_value :'+cur_shot)
                print('sel_index :'+str(cur_index))

                next_shot_index = int(cur_index)+1
                print('nextshot_index ='+str(next_shot_index))
                next_shot_text = self.lst_shots.item(next_shot_index).text()
                next_shot_val = int(next_shot_text[2:])
                print('nextshot value ='+str(next_shot_val))

                insert_space = next_shot_val - cur_shot_val
                print(str(insert_space))

                if no_of_shots > (insert_space-1) :
                    print "not enough space - please reduce shots to insert"
                else:
                    print('insert the shots')
                    for x in range(cur_shot_val,(cur_shot_val+no_of_shots) ):
                        print (str(x))
                        make_render_folders.insert_shot_folder(spot_path,  x+1)

    make_render_folders.populate_shot_list(self)
    self.lst_shots.setCurrentRow(0)

@pyqtSignature("")
def on_btn_quit_released(self):
    print 'quit'
    self.close()

@pyqtSignature("")
def on_cmb_mode_currentIndexChanged(self,  ret_text):
    print ret_text

@pyqtSignature("")   
def on_le_proj_path_editingFinished(self):
    print "editingFinished le_proj_path"

def on_le_new_spot_name_textChanged(self):
    if len(self.le_new_spot_name.text()) > 0 :
        self.btn_add_spot.setEnabled(True)
    else :
        self.btn_add_spot.setEnabled(False)

@pyqtSignature("")
def on_btn_add_spot_released(self):
    v_NewSpotFolder = self.le_new_spot_name.text()
    v_rPath =  self.le_proj_path.text()
    x = make_render_folders.create_spot_folder(v_NewSpotFolder,v_rPath)
    if x :
        self.le_new_spot_name.clear()    
        make_render_folders.populate_spots_list(self)

@pyqtSignature("")
def on_actionLoad_Project_triggered(self):
    print "actionLoad_Project"

    self.lst_shots.clear()
    self.lst_spots.clear()

    proj_dir = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select Project'))
    print proj_dir

    if os.path.exists(proj_dir):
        print 'the file is there'
    elif os.access(os.path.dirname(proj_dir), os.W_OK):
        print 'the file does not exists but write privileges are given'
    else:
        print 'can not write there'

    p = os.path.join(proj_dir+os.sep,'renders')

    self.le_proj_path.setText(p)

    make_render_folders.populate_spots_list(self)

@pyqtSignature("")    
def on_actionConfig_triggered(self):
    print "config"
    self.prefs.show()

@pyqtSignature("")
def on_actionQuit_triggered(self):
    print "ActionQuit"

@pyqtSignature("")
def on_btn_get_folders_released(self):
    make_render_folders.populate_spots_list(self)

def on_lst_spots_itemClicked (self):
    print "got you"

    self.lst_shots.clear()
    make_render_folders.populate_shot_list(self)
```

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Event handling for the Prefs window can go anywhere. Personally I always prefer to give each window its own file.

So the py files would look something like:

- Mainwindow.py (Main form events etc)
- Ui_make_render_folders.py (Qt Designer generated UI)
- prefs.py (Prefs form events etc)
- ui_prefs.py (Qt Designer generated UI)
- your other files...

**Initialisation:** (MainWindow.py)

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow
from Ui_make_render_folders import Ui_MainWindow

#prefs here refers to the file: prefs.py. PrefWindow is the class within this file.
from prefs import PrefWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        #Better way to initialise
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.main = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.main.setupUi(self)

        #initialise prefs to variable
        self.prefs = PrefWindow(self)

        # Rest of init...
```

Note: initialising of second form will be similar to above.
You should place all events for prefs form within its class.

From the function that calls Prefs:

```
@pyqtSlot()
def on_actionConfig_triggered(self):
    print "config"
    self.prefs.exec_()  # Will block main window while its open.
    # Use self.prefs.show() if you want user to be able to interact with main window
```

**Finally:** pyqtSignature

On http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/old_style_signals_slots.html it states that:

'The QtCore.pyqtSignature() serves the same purpose as the pyqtSlot() decorator but has a less Pythonic API.'

Better to use pyqtSlot()